# Setting Cell Datatype at runtime deleting the cell data in apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

i have java code to read excel file using apache poi.i have some requirement and i am setting Cell data type to String while reading the cell data at runtime. for ex

before:
   `cellData.getStringCellValue() --> "Ramki"`

after:
   `cellData.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
   System.out.println("The cell data is: " + cellData.getStringCellValue()); ---> ""`

can we change the cell data type at runtime.

i am using apache POI 3.7

please help me on this.

Thanks,
Ramki.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, and what problem you're having. Why are you setting an existing cell type to a string for example?

Comment: i want to handle numeric data and string data in the code. first i will check whether data type of cell is numberic or not? if it is not number i want to change that cell type to string (irrespective of type wheter is formula,error,..etc)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you're after is basically the text of what Excel would display for each cell?

If so, the key class for you will be [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) which does this for you.

If you take a look at the [ExcelExtractor](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/ExcelExtractor.java) class in POI you'll see a fully worked example of doing this.

```
HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(k);

switch(cell.getCellType()) {
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        text.append(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
        break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        text.append(
              _formatter.formatCellValue(cell)
        );
        break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        text.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
        text.append(ErrorEval.getText(cell.getErrorCellValue()));
        break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        if(outputCellFormulas) {
            text.append(cell.getCellFormula());
        } else {
            switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    HSSFRichTextString str = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                    if(str != null && str.length() > 0) {
                        text.append(str.toString());
                    }
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                   HSSFCellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
                   if(style == null) {
                      text.append( cell.getNumericCellValue() );
                   } else {
                 text.append(
                       _formatter.formatRawCellContents(
                             cell.getNumericCellValue(),
                             style.getDataFormat(),
                             style.getDataFormatString()
                       )
                 );
                   }
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    text.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    text.append(ErrorEval.getText(cell.getErrorCellValue()));
                    break;

            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected cell type (" + cell.getCellType() + ")");
}
```